# Deleting Rows in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete some specific rows in a Dataframe in Python . The dataframe consists of a series of tables and we have to delete the rows where only the first cell has values . For example the in the bottom , rows highlighted in yellows.

[image]

Comment: Are the yellow marked row cells are NULL except the first column?

Comment: Does "where only the first cell has values" mean "empty string" or NA? What is the dtype of the first column? (look at `df.info()`)

Comment: @ Pavan yes first cell is only having values rest are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Unwanted rows have specific part string common then you could explicitly delete those using

```
df_new = df[~df.columnName.str.contains("FINANCIAL SERVICES")]
```

and if the row cells are NULL use **dropna**

**`df.dropna(subset=df.columns[1:], how= 'all', inplace = True)`**